# After 16.04.1 upgrade Samba will not start

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, samba

I had an interrupted upgrade from 14.01.1 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS, so some packages were not properly installed and a lot of dependencies were improperly installed.  I believe that I have cleared all of those issues up, but I cannot get samba to start.

When I attempt to start either smbd or nmbd I receive the following error:

```
root@xyz:/etc/samba$ sudo systemctl start smbd.service
Failed to start smbd.service: Unit smbd.service not found.
```

I have gone through the smb.conf file and ensured that security = share is commented out (most common issue observed on this forum).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So, finally fixed it.  Based on response at [Samba does not launch after upgrading to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762705/samba-does-not-launch-after-upgrading-to-16-04), I had to purge all samba packages first.

So, I ran:

```
aptitude purge samba libnss-winbind libpam-winbind samba-dbg system-config-samaba winbind smbclient samba-testsuite samba-common-bin samba-dev samba-doc samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules
```

(I don't know where I picked some of those up, I think I was following someone's solution that said to install samba*)

Then I ran

```
aptitude install samba libnss-winbind:amd64 libpam-winbind:amd64 winbind -f
```

(make sure correct system architecture is used -- mine is an AMD64).

```
service smbd start
service nmbd start
```

then worked!