# samba won't start, 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, samba

Xubuntu 16.04.1, `apt-get update` today, but this has been an ongoing problem for a number of weeks. I removed the `/etc/samba` directory entirely before running:

```
root@lorne:/etc# apt-get install -f samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
samba is already the newest version (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error
code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running systemctl and journalctl doesn't give any insight.

```
● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)    
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-12-19 11:43:44 PST; 2min 54s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8584 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne smbd[8584]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne smbd[8584]:    ...fail!
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

and

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit smbd.service has begun starting up.
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne smbd[8584]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne smbd[8584]:    ...fail!
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
-- Subject: Unit smbd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit smbd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 19 11:43:44 lorne systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've purged the apt cache, run `apt-get purge samba`, and deleted the `/etc/samba` directory. I also ran through the steps here: https://askubuntu.com/a/814747/632686 to no avail.

Help?

Thanks,
Anthony.

Comment: Can you post any more detailed logs if the are any? Like in `/var/log/samba/`

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no recent logs in there. In fact, the last logs are 0-byte `log.smbd` and `log.nmdb` files from May 2016 (which wasn't the last time samba was running, but I don't know exactly when that would have been)

Comment: Does it say anything in syslog?

Comment: syslog has the same info:

Comment: Erm, here's the log snippet: http://pastebin.com/pBYujDCS (pastebin b/c char limit in replies?)