# Samba not starting after upgrade to 16.04.3

Tags: samba

I've just updated to 16.04.3 and the samba service will not start now.  The following error is returned:

```
flyinhawaiian@flyinserver:~$ sudo service smbd restart
Failed to restart smbd.service: Unit smbd.service not found.
```

I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge samba
$ sudo apt list --installed | egrep samba
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And removing all packages listed and autoremoving, then rebooting and reinstalling samba.

This is all with just the default smb.conf file.  I tried with the config file I was using, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: ...and what was it before 16.04.3?

Comment: 12.04.  The server had been off for about a year while I moved and I just got it started back up.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/814398/after-16-04-1-upgrade-samba-will-not-start. Also, how do update from 12.04 to 16.04.3? Didn't know there is a way to do it.

Comment: I have tried that also.  I just used do-release-upgrade.  I think it went to 14.04 first.

Comment: looking through winscp, the file /etc/init.d/smbd is not there, trying to open it gives a file not found.