# Samba not starting after upgrade to 16.04, mostly a systemd question

Tags: samba, systemd, logging

Yeah, after upgrading to 16.04 smbd did not start because I still had security=share in the config file. That question is answered here [Samba does not launch after upgrading to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762705/samba-does-not-launch-after-upgrading-to-16-04).

But I have a different question. Where are the error messages from samba? Starting failed, and I got told to look at systemctl status smb.service or journalctl -xe. Both told me the process exited with an error, but didn't log any error message from smbd itself.

Is systemd THAT unusable?

Edit: or: please point me to any way i could have seen that error *on my system* instead of just googling for "smbd doesn't start after upgrade to 16.04".

Comment: what is the output when you try to use "testparm?" also you can check the logs which was located at /var/log/samba/* and see the latest generated logs of samba or modified by your system.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is long fixed, what I would like to know is why there was nothing useful in the systemd output...

Comment: Each of the services have their own loggings initially systemd journaling handles some of the services and if it can it will show errors that is why linux have its services like samba to have its own logfiles for a much more thorough information of services functions that includes errors encountered.

Comment: @Yien, yes, but the underlying problem is that "the systemd way" has a strong wind trying hard to divert us from oldschool direct manual config. or log-digging  etc. So, as OP, I had fallen to the same trap, that OK, so if we are not supposed to do things "the old UNIX way" any more, but told to use the systemd facilities instead, then our mindset inevitably shifts toward expecting those tools to provide full service, and add value (in this use case, too), instead of making things more complicated by now having to use *both* the systemd tools *and* inspecting the same old logs etc.